# How to Create a Button in a PDF to Select and Copy all Text from a Single Field

Tags: pdf, adobe

I need a person to be able to input information into a field in a PDF then later be able to select and copy all information from that field with a single click so they may paste it into another field on a website.

Purpose. I am trying to create a master application which people with disabilities may complete and use as a simple way to fill out other applications. I don't believe I can create an autofill ability which will be useful for the thousands of different methods of job application but I want the human to be able to select the correct field then, in as few clicks as possible, copy information from a field in the PDF and paste it into one they deem as appropriate in another application.

I am an idiot, this is a passion project.

Comment: That's not possible. Acrobat JavaScript can't put text on the clipboard.

Comment: Sorry. You'd asked to do it via a button. That's what's not possible. Of course you can do it manually.

Comment: @KJ thank you. I think I may simply want to create an online form rather than a PDF. My reason for PDF was to allow local storage so people would not need to access sensitive information online through a site, we will need to create a secure way to store PPI. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler depending on user cases to work inside the browser framework. Here is totally non typical usage for copy data from local personal html into remote form. IT depends heavily on the remote site accepting it can be embedded as if a local frame thus not useful for generic use but may work for controlled caseload's

[image]

[image]